# Lock camera in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that lets a user take a picture with the camera.  I would like to only allow the user to take landscape photos, not portrait.  Is there a way for me to lock the camera orientation?

Below is the code I am using:

```
func takePhoto() {
    //If a camera is available on this device, go to camera.  If not, present an error message.
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
        //Create the image picker controller
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        //Present the camera view
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is no camera available", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction) in alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to lock the camera orientation

The camera is a physical object. Its orientation has nothing to do with your app. The only way to "lock the camera orientation" is to reach out and grab the user's wrist so that s/he can't turn the device.